# How should speed be expressed in Frenet-Serret frame of reference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, speed

I'm looking for the equation of motion of the ball on a vertical plane with a cylindrical profile. I guess that means I have to use the frame of reference of [Frenet-Serret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) here.

Why is the speed of the ball on the top $\vec{v}=R\dot\theta \vec{T}$?

I guess this has to do with the definition of radians and that the ball should move proportionataly to the radians change on the vertical plane express by $\vec{T}$ (in the Fernet-Serret frame of reference).

[image]

(Translation: A point of mass $m$ slides frictionless in the vertical plane along a cylindrical path of radius $R$).

Comment: What is "SERRET - FRENET"? You might want to translate the description above the picture: "A frictionless point mass **m** slides in the vertical plane along a cylindrical path of radius R"

Comment: According to the [Frenet-Serret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) wiki page, $T$ is the tangent unit vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we differentiate the [definition of radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), $l = R\theta$, with respect to time we get $v = \dot R\theta + R \dot\theta$.

As $R$ is constant, $\dot R = 0$, so we have $v = R \dot\theta$.

However $v$, $R$ and $\dot\theta$ are scalars, whereas you want the vector. So multiply by the tangent unit vector, $\hat{T}$, and we arrive at $\vec{v} = R \dot\theta \hat{T}$.

Comment: Note that it is possible that there comes a point where $R$ is not constant... in which case the analysis is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: True, but so long as the cylindrical profile is followed $R$ is constant. If however, the ball falls off the side (at $\theta = \pi/2$) then the subsequent motion can be treated separately.

Comment: Usually in these problems the ball _will_ lose contact, and computing the angle at which that takes place is part of the exercise. "Glisse ... sur un profil" is ambiguous - "slides... _on_ a profile". Could be "follows along", or "sits on top of (and may lose contact)". Just thought that your answer would be more complete if you added the extra term (which is zero if $\dot R = 0$)

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear, the definition of [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) is $l = R\theta$, where $l$ is the arc length, $R$ is the radius and $\theta$ is the angle subtended by the arc. [This animation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Circle_radians.gif) on wikipedia superbly explains what a radian is.

Comment: @Floris, that's an excellent point! I've edited my answer to be complete. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @Judge sorry I can't vote twice...